# How to delete components from managed (release) package Winter14

Tags: appexchange, isv

I want to delete some unused components from our managed package. I did hear this was possible with the winter14 release. I think this was on a pilot basis. What is the criteria to be part of the pilot program?

Would a case requesting to be part of pilot program do? or are there any other criteria

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs this is no longer in developer preview and should be available for all appropriate editions:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=viewing_deleted_components.htm&language=en_US

However, I believe you can only do this if you are an ISV partner and the managed package is publicly listed on the app exchange.  I have some components I'd like to delete from packages that we built for internal use, but I don't have that option.

Comment: How do i delete the components? cant find any place from where i can delete it in the package. We are an isv company and have the package listed in appexchange

Comment: I think you need to get Salesforce to enable this in the developer edition that you build your package from.

Comment: oh ok.. a case on partner portal should do i guess

Comment: Does anyone have a screen shot of what this should look like when enabled? We are an ISV and told we had this feature but haven't seen anything on how it actually appears or is used.